# How to exclude duplicate package from added 3rd party solution

Tags: android, duplicates, build.gradle

I'm writing an application where integrated two external lib. Project Clean & build is fine but when I tried to run it on device it displaying following error related Duplication of Jar file:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForAzovaDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/webrtc/voiceengine/BuildInfo.class
```

Any suggestion how to handle such common scenario ?

Comment: you could give `exclude` a try.

Comment: that's useful but I'm not sure about group name & module name what I should pickup. I tried with ./gradlew app:dependencies but didn't found anything relevant. Any suggestion ?

Comment: if you press twice on shift on android studio, the "search everywhere" pop up shows up. Type there the name of duplicate class and you will find out who else is using it

Comment: That's known thing, I'm asking about what to pass as an Group name & Module name. Since I'm getting conflict in a single class and that is also BuildInfo.java :|.

Comment: it is `BuildInfo.class`

Comment: Yes, I mean same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133409/discussion-between-shubh-and-blackbelt).